# Problem with Array Modifier in tutorial "How to Create Robotic Arms in Blender"

Tags: modeling, modifiers, rigging

[image: The Image After Applying Array Modifier][image: Then Applied Object Offset...][image: The Claw I made][image: The Original Claw I should've made]

I've been trying to follow the [workflow of the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2HCxy4Kh4E&list=PL2DcM9Gsef16GjHLpFtYS1A0iBlsCoq6G) as closely as possible, but I got stuck at the "Modeling and rigging the claw" stage. Originally I needed to generate three claws that were exactly the same shape.

When I applied object offset to claw duplicator(Triangle one), somehow all three ended up being different sizes. The three should have been exactly the same size and shape. Since the same question was posted I think this needs to be addressed.

Comment: Pls provide blend file

Comment: There's a comment below the video by 'ishmael mercado' saying that you should apply all transforms to the claw duplicator at around [9:45](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2HCxy4Kh4E) in the tutorial rather than clearing the location. That's the next option below 'Clear' on the menu and apparently solves the problem you're having..

Comment: Resolved. Thanks to you.